# Класс для управления БД

Tags: php, классы

Добрый день! У меня такой вопрос, стоит ли конструировать класс для работы с БД (на сайте-визитки) или же ограничиться использованием стандартных средств расширения mysqli? Если стоит, то порекомендуйте готовые примеры-классы для работы с БД на просторах бескрайнего интернета...

Comment: велосипеды уже делали.

Comment: под велосипедом понимается расширение mysqli? Или классы специальные для работы с БД?

Comment: @IntegralAL велосипед это например [PDO][1]


  [1]: http://uk3.php.net/manual/ru/intro.pdo.php

Comment: тоесть заморачиваться с созданием отдельного класса по управлению БД не стоит?

Comment: @IntegralAL используйте наиболее удобный инструмент. Сколько вы будете писать и отлаживать свой класс? Цените своё время и время заказчика. Воспользуйтесь чем-нибудь готовым. А в свободное время пишите и отлаживайте свой собственный инструмент работы с бд.

Comment: Вот вам ещё вдогонку [Почему стоит пользоваться PDO для работы с базой данных][1]


  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/137664/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал [`SafeMySql`](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql).